# Openoffice Calc Skip cell that are empty

Tags: openoffice-calc

I need to copy the content of a cell to another sheet after comparing.
So I am using the following code to compare two colums.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP($A2;$B$2:$B$20007;1;0);"")
```

This gives me the content of cell 1 and if the string exists or blank if it does not exist.
Now I need to copy only the string that does not exists to another sheet

Can anyone help?

Comment: This question is not clear enough. Copying something to an other sheet is not possible using formulas. For this some kind of code is needed. Or is the need having a formula which pulls all strings from column A that does not exists in column B? Or simply filter (AutoFilter) all rows where your formula results in "" and copy those rows to the other sheet.

Comment: oh, that's why it didn't work. Do you know how to do it in the same sheet ?

Comment: Hm, no, maybe now I've been not clear enough :-) .  Copying is not possible with formulas at all, even on the same sheet. A formula only can result in a value. So is the need having a formula which pulls the strings from column A that does not exists in column B? If so, then this formula must be stored in multiple cells, as each formula can only return one value. So in what column shall the formulas be stored in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have the following example:

[image]

Formula in `C2` and downwards is your

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP($A2;$B$2:$B$20007;1;0);"")
```

Formula in `D2` and downwards is

```
=IF($C2="";$A2;"")
```

But the second is not necessary in my opinion, since we could simply use AutoFilter to get ColA not contained in ColB:

[image]

If the need is filtering values in ColA which are not contained in ColB using a formula, then the following would be possible:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
{=INDEX($Sheet1.$A$2:$A$20007;SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($Sheet1.$B$2:$B$20007;$Sheet1.$A$2:$A$20007)=0;ROW($Sheet1.$A$2:$A$20007)-1);ROW(A1)))}
```

This is an array formula. Put it into the cell without the curly brackets. Then choosee `fx` - the Function Wizard - and tick the `[x] Array` checkbox left down. Then click `OK` in the Function Wizard.

Now **copy** the formula and **paste** it in `A3:An`. Do **not** pull with the fill square. If you would do that, then you would only enlage the target cells of the array formula. You would not copy the formula down.

Comment: Hi,  Works great! I chose to go with solution 1 as it seemed more "solid".  After that I copied the content manually. Thank you very much